# How to get Getter backing field from PropertyInfo?

Tags: c#, reflection, inotifypropertychanged, getter, propertyinfo

I have a class as follows:

```
class Foo : PropertyChangedBase {
    private int _property;

    public int Property {
       get { return _property; }
       set { OnAssignPropertyChanged("Property", () => _property, value); }
}
```

`PropertyChangedBase` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` with the following methods:

```
    protected void OnAssignmentPropertyChanged<T>(string propertyName, Expression<Func<T>> fieldExpression, T value)
    {
        var get = fieldExpression.Compile();
        if (get().Equals(value))
        {
            return;
        }

        //  invoke set property method
        SetProperty(fieldExpression, value);
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void SetProperty<T>(Expression<Func<T>> fieldExpression, T value)
    {
        if (fieldExpression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fieldExpression));
        }

        var memberExpression = fieldExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("fieldExpression");
        }

        var field = memberExpression.Member as FieldInfo;
        if (field == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("fieldExpression");
        }

        field.SetValue(this, value);
    }
```

I would prefer to call:

```
OnAssignPropertyChanged(() => Property, value);
```

The only way this will work is if I can get the backing field for the property getter and then pass that to `SetProperty`. Is it possible to get the `FieldInfo` or target member from the property get method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general answer, yes you can do, at least under controlled conditions. But the only case you should do this is when you are absoluty sure what you are doing and only with limited support, because there will be cases you can not handle.

Have a look at the answer here: [Find all property references using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997245/find-all-property-references-using-reflection/). The target is a bit different but the approach is similar for finding field references. Since the answer there already includes the necessary code i will just outline the way to go:

All metadata items in .Net are referenced by tokens. To get tokens used inside a method you have to parse the [MethodBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbody.getilasbytearray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (by skipping all the things you wont inspect) and then [resolve the found tokens in their module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.module.resolvemember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Remember to use the [BitConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.bitconverter.toint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when reading the tokens from the stream to resolve them.

But now to the down side; the only time you can really safely use this to find the backing fields of a properties getter, is when you find a simple get method, with a well defined opcode sequence like Ldfld, Ret or something like that. Maybe you can define a few patterns that the C# compiler will emit for simple and autoimplemented properties. If you find anything different there is no other way as to resign and throw an exception, because the getter could contain any code.
Like always with reflection, only use whitelist approaches, check for the conditions you expect and throw exeptions in any other case or you will run into a NullReferenceException sooner or later.

If this is worth the trouble is for you to decide, but in general you could do this since .Net 2.0 and do not even need a fancy external lib.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. The use case is very specific for classes that inherit from the base class. Based on our coding guide, we can enforce the rules for use. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, in general case you *can't*. Just compare two classes:

```
public class Test {
  private int _propA;
  private int _propB;

  public int PropA {get { return _propA; }}
  public int PropB {get { return _propB; }}
} 

public class TestSwapped {
  private int _propA;
  private int _propB;

  // please, notice swapped backing fields
  public int PropA {get { return _propB; }}
  public int PropB {get { return _propA; }}
}
```

you'll get identical `PropertyInfo[]` and `FieldInfo[]` arrays but *different* backing fields

Comment: You will have to compare the bodies of the accessors, of course. That is hard, as any IL code could be in there. I built in Release mode your example and tried `typeof(TestSwapped).GetProperty("PropA").GetMethod.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray()` and similar for `Test`. It simply loads "this" onto the stack, loads the relevant field (`ldfld`) therefrom, and returns that. The difference was seen in the argument to the `ldfld` instruction.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen: havig *IL code*, sure, we can find out (or at least propose a reasonable guess) the backing field in the simple cases (i.e. `return _propB;`); in *general case*, however, it's *impossible* (Alan Turing halt theorem modification). E.g. get `get {if (_propA > 0) return _propB; else return _propB + 1;}` first field loaded (depends on compiler) is `_propA` backing field is `_propB`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: excellent point on the properties. My implementation is specific to simple getters: `get { return _field; }` ...Models or ViewModels implementing our property change notification should be simple getters.

Answer (score 1):

In pursuing this for a different question, here is an extension method for the simple cases - an autogenerated backing field, or a get that just returns a backing field:

```
public static class MethodInfoExt {
    const int IL_ldarg0 = 0x02;
    const int IL_ldfld = 0x7B;

    public static FieldInfo FieldInfoFromGetAccessor(this MethodInfo getAccessorMI) {
        var body = getAccessorMI.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
        if (body[0] == IL_ldarg0 && body[1] == IL_ldfld) {
            var fieldToken = BitConverter.ToInt32(body, 2);
            return getAccessorMI.DeclaringType.Module.ResolveField(fieldToken);
        }
        else
            return default;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not. Property can have no backing fields or sets of backing fields.
Even set property can have no backing fields at all.

```
public Int32 Prop
{
set { Debug.WriteLine(value.ToString()); }
get { return 1; }
}
```

What are you expecting to get in FieldInfo?

Comment: In properties with auto-accessors you can get the auto-backing fields via reflection: e.g. { get; set; } has auto-backing fields. So, I would presume you could get the backing field if, as in my example, the getter actually returns the field;

Comment: Well, you can not as far as I know.

Comment: It possibly could, but it's a huge work for the compiler. Although the simple cases are straightforward, the cases can easily become complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Property is just a syntax sugar for a pair of set/get methods, or mutators. Being a method allows them to contain as much code as needed, including being just empty and, of course, there is no requirement to have a backing field from compiler perspective.