# How to parse a method invocation in IL bytes?

Tags: disassembly, system.reflection, cil

I know how to use the `System.Reflection` API, but not how to parse IL (Intermediate Language), though I do know how to parse x86 opcodes for what that's worth.

Now I want to find all the methods in an assembly which invoke a given method -- e.g., given a method named `Namespace.Classname.Methodname`, which methods in the assembly invoke it?

Assume I have the `MethodInfo` for the method in question.

To do this I suppose I must parse the bytes returned from the [MethodBody.GetILAsByteArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbody.getilasbytearray?view=net-8.0) method (which I don't know how to do).

The Note in the API Help says,

> Parsing method bodies requires a thorough understanding of metadata and MSIL instruction formats. Information can be found in the [Common Language Infrastructure (CLI)](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-335/) documentation, especially "Partition II: Metadata Definition and Semantics".

... which is a 500-page document.

Can you give me any hint of how to do it, outline the algorithm I'll implement, suggest an easy way to do it using a tool or library like ILSpy, or reference a suitable introduction to the topic before I start the wade through the referfence manual?

If it helps, I don't want to parse everything in the IL -- only to parse it just enough to find the method calls, especially the calls to constructors.

Comment: It's [been done](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/coreclr/ildasm), many [more](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil) like this.

Comment: Depending on the use case, this could be an option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997245/find-all-property-references-using-reflection/33034906#33034906

Comment: @thehennyy That's beautiful, thank you. If that were an answer instead of a comment I could upvote or accept it.

Comment: If you need to get MethodInfo you can use [this](https://github.com/jl0pd/LightDecompiler/blob/main/src/jl0pd.Reflection.LightDecompiler/LightDecompiler.cs). If you need to inspect methods from dll which you don't want to load then use Mono.Cecil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IL byte stream can be parsed using the `System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes` class. The opcodes `OperandType` field tells you how many bytes to read, to reach the next opcode. While iterating over the stream, metadata tokens can be resolved using the `Module.ResolveMember` method. Have a look here for an example on how to find property getter tokens: [Find all property references using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997245/find-all-property-references-using-reflection/33034906). The code can easily adapted to search for any kind of tokens or instructions you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently doing it with the `ICSharpCode.Decompiler` package as shown here:

- https://github.com/cwellsx/apis/blob/main/src.dotnet/Core.IL/Decompiler.cs

I tried disassembling the IL myself however I had a problem/exception:

- I was trying to use a method named `Module.ResolveMethod`
- The subclass of `Module` which I instantiated was `System.Reflection.TypeLoading.RoModule`
- Its `ResolveMethod` throws:

  > Resolving tokens is not supported on assemblies loaded by a MetadataLoadContext

  Apparently the problem was my using `MetadataLoadContext` to load the assembly to be decompiled -- if I do that then "I can't get there from here" i.e. it's the wrong technology.

  See also this topic which says the functionality is missing/unimplemented:

  > [Support resolving metadata tokens in MetadataLoadContext](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/87657)

I don't know what technology the `ICSharpCode.Decompiler` uses instead to load assemblies, or why it's different, but apparently it has no such problem -- so I used it.

Its "abstract syntax tree" is optimized towards decompiling to a high-level-language (C#) syntax, so its AST output wasn't what I wanted. Instead I used it to get the IL, and I made my own subclass of "Visitor" to do what I wanted with the various types of opcode.

The classes or interfaces of the package are mostly `public` so I was able to do that.

I only had to copy-and-paste a little of the code from the `CSharpDecompiler` in order to instantiate another of its types I needed i.e. `MetadataModule`.